# Why does reading char 'g' into an int produce the number -858993460 in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin, cout

I was doing an exercise for a class and I decided to see what would happen if I type in a `char` when the code was expecting an `int`. I put in the letter `'g'` just to see what would happen... it output `-858993460` and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>      
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int test;

 cout << "Please enter a even integer or a odd integer. " << endl;

 cin >> test;
 cout << test; //here is where i got the -858993460



 if (test % 2)
 {cout << "TRIANGLE" << endl;}
 else
 {cout << "SQUARE" << endl;}



 return 0;

 }
```

So where does that `-858993460` come from?

Comment: -858993460 is 0xcccccccc in hex. It does mean that `int` is uninitialized in Visual Studio debug mode.

Comment: -858993460 = 0xCCCCCCCC which means [you've accessed uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of [std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) changed from C++11. Before C++11,

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

This seems to be the case. `test` is not initialized; then you got a random value printed out. Note that this is undefined behavior in fact.

And since C++11,

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.

That means you'll get the value `0` after C++11.

Comment: Oh! okay, so, -858993460 a default\random value and nothing was assigned to `test`. this makes sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the result of the read, you'll see that nothing was read.

```
if (cin >> test) {
    cout << "read " << test << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "read failed" << endl;
}
```

The value you're printing is `test`'s uninitialized value. It can change from run to run. Technically, printing it is undefined behavior, so your program could even crash, although that's unlikely to happen in practice.